# matlab boolean operator

Tags: matlab, boolean, ascii, boolean-logic

I have a problem with the MATLAB boolean operator.

Non-ASCII range:

- 0 - 2
- Above 128

The if condition becomes true only if there are no characters in the above ranges.

```
if any( out.autoc < 128 & out.autoc ~= 0 & out.autoc ~= 1 & ...
        out.cprom < 128 & out.cprom ~= 0 & out.cprom ~= 1 )    
    fprintf(file_1, '%s,' , out.autoc);
    fprintf(file_1, '%s,' , out.cprom);
    fprintf(file_1, '\r\n');
else
    display(fileName);
end
```

The problem occurs when I do the following:

```
if any( out.autoc < 128 & out.autoc > 2 & ...
        out.cprom < 128 & out.cprom > 2 )
    fprintf(file_1, '%s,' , out.autoc);
    fprintf(file_1, '%s,' , out.cprom);
    fprintf(file_1, '\r\n');
else
    display(fileName);
end
```

It doesn't work as expected - the condition seems to be false all the time. Why?

Comment: Can you provide some code that we can use to test it?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you specify that the "ASCII range" is [0, 2] and [129, 255]. To my knowledge, standard ASCII is [0, 127], including some 30-odd control characters.

Next, you say "above 128" but then check with "`< 128`". This means above 127, not 128- it will be false for 128 as well as 129, which I assume is not what you want, because you say "above 128". However, ASCII doesn't go to 128 from what I recall- it's a 7-bit format from 0 to 127, inclusive. And 127 is supposed to be "delete", so I'm not sure if even including 127 matters in practice.

Likewise, your second block has "`> 2`", which excludes 0, 1 and 2 (2 isn't greater than 2). Importantly, your first block *doesn't* exclude 2- only 0 and 1. 2 is apparently "Start of text", so I wouldn't be surprised if all ASCII strings have it, which would explain why the second condition is always false.

Comment: by ascii range i didnt mean the actual ascii range. I just want to allow ascii characters in those ranges to make the if condition true.